# Collecting and analyzing personal movement logs?

Tags: qgis, movement-data

I'm looking for a program that logs what specific locations I've been to & how long I've been there, etc. Is this possible on QGIS?

For example, if I took my laptop to the store today at 1pm (A1) for 30 mins & then went to the gym (B1) for 40 mins at 3pm; the log should look like this:

A1:
Arrived at 1pm and stayed until 1:30pm on 16/03/2019? Yes.

B1:
Arrived at 3pm and stayed until 3:40pm on 16/03/2019? Yes.

This is obviously a very simplified version of what I want. I just want some simple data to work with for the time being.

Comment: get a **tracking device** and then play with the data with qgis ...

Comment: What type of tracking device would I need? Also, are you sure it's possible on Qgis? I probably would need to start from scratch if no one has done something like this.

Comment: By the way, is there a tracking device I can get on my laptop which is usable offline? I don't want to carry around a mobile phone.

Comment: A simple tracking device just collects point data of your location at specified intervals. You could use QGIS to aggregate the data into a log like you want, but that's actually more complicated than just collecting thousands of points. It sounds like you want to track a person to determine whether they went where they said they would and stayed there as long as they said they did. That's **definitely** been done before.

Comment: Has it been done before using QGIS or some other proprietary enterprise software?